# Is there a way to have a side by side comparison in visual studio of a remote file and a local file using remote ssh?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to see if there is a way to have a side by side comparison of a remote file that I can edit using remote ssh and a local file that I point to. I am interested in something like meld is doing but one file remote one file local.

Thanks lots in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following incantation allows changes to be made to local files, but not to remote files. Because you are ok with `meld`, Visual Studio is not required:

```sh
$ meld /path/to/file_or_directory <(ssh user@domain cat /path/to/file_or_directory)&
```

The Meld plugin for Visual Studio does not support comparing with a remote file over ssh.